# C Linked List Adding New Node Issue

Tags: c, linked-list

The final complete program is under below link. Thanks every one who respond me.

Completed program: http://pastebin.com/1Qrs11JE

Question:

I have an annoying issue with linked-list in C Language. I have an homework that I have to submit tomorrow. I have been trying to solve this problem since yesterday, but I couldn't. I think problem is appending new node to the linked-list, but I get the error while trying to view records in linked-list. I am facing meaningles result and thr program ends up with an error.

You can see the code in the link below which more readable or from below.
Link: http://pastebin.com/Ugtue6JT

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// structure definition
 struct node {
char name[50];
int age;
int student_no;
char nationality[50];
struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *NODE_T;

// function declarations
void enter_new_data();
void remove_existing_data();
void display_all_data();
void show_options();
NODE_T getnode();
void freenode(NODE_T p);
void free_buffer();
void continue_f(char message[100]);

// global variables
char ch;

// create linked-list's main holder variable
NODE_T students,conductor;

int main(){

// allocate memory for the node link-list holder
students = NULL;
//students->next = 0; // initialize next to 0 for first node of linked-list

// show the options that user has
show_options();

return 1;
}

// this function will list options that user can apply
void show_options(){

system("cls"); // clear screen

int opt,opt_bool=0;

printf("%s\n\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n","The Options You Have","1. Add New Student's Record","2. Delete An Existing Student's Record","3. Display The List Of Students","4. Exit");


while(opt_bool != 1){
    printf("Operation:  ");
    scanf("%d",&opt);

    if(opt == 1 || opt == 2 || opt == 3 || opt == 4){
        opt_bool = 1;
    }

}

// check the operation and go to the operation
if(opt == 1){ // adding record
    enter_new_data();
} else if(opt == 2){ // removing record

} else if(opt == 3){ // displaying records
    display_all_data();
} else if(opt == 4){ // exit the program
    exit(0);
}
}

// enter new student data into linked-list
void enter_new_data(){

system("cls"); // clear screen

// get a new node
NODE_T p = getnode();

printf("You are entering a new student's record\n");

// take student's name
printf("Student's Name: ");
scanf("%s",p->name);
free_buffer();

// take student's age
printf("Student's Age: ");
scanf("%d",&p->age);
free_buffer();

// take student's number
printf("Student's Number: ");
scanf("%d",&p->student_no);
free_buffer();

// take student's nationality
printf("Student's Nationality: ");
scanf("%s",p->nationality);
free_buffer();

// set p->next next value of last node of linked-list, which is equal to 0
p->next = 0;

printf("%s, %d, %d, %s",p->name,p->age,p->student_no,p->nationality);


// if there is no any node yet, add node p as first node
if(students == NULL) {
    students = p;
} else {

    conductor = students; // assign linked-list to the conductor to traverse

    // reach the last node
    while (conductor->next != 0)
    {
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }

    conductor->next = p; // append the node p to the linked list
}

freenode(p); // set free node p

continue_f("Adding new record is done."); // ask press any key to continue

show_options(); // show options

}

// to display all data of linked list
void display_all_data(){

system("cls"); // clear screen

printf("The Student Records\n\n");

printf("%s%7s%18s%15s","STUDENT'S NAME","AGE","STUDENT NUMBER","NATIONALITY"); // captions

freenode(conductor);
conductor = getnode();
conductor = students; // assign linked-list to the conductor to traverse

if (conductor != NULL ) { /* Makes sure there is a place to start */
    // traverse untill last node
    while ( conductor->next != 0)
    {

        printf("\n%s%7d%18d%15s",conductor->name,conductor->age,conductor->student_no,conductor->nationality); // record

        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
  } else {
    printf("\n\n There is not any record yet.");
  }

  continue_f("Listing records is done."); // ask press any key to continue

  show_options(); // show options
}

// create new node
NODE_T getnode(void){
   NODE_T p;
   p = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   return p;
}

// set free a node
void freenode(NODE_T p){
    free(p);
}

// clear the buffer if there are any extra data in it
void free_buffer(){
    while (getchar() != '\n') { }   
}

void continue_f(char message[100]){
     printf("\n\n%s\nPress any key to continue...",message);
     getch(); // wait for pushing any key from user
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Neither `<conio.h>` nor `<malloc.h>` are standard headers, btw.

Comment: @melpomene: use the `[mcve]` tag :)

Comment: `conductor = getnode(); conductor = students;` Do you understand that the first statement in the sequence is useless and only wastes memory? Or perhaps you can explain what `freenode(p)` is doing in a function that enters new data? There are many other problems, but for now try to remove all calls to `freenode` and also the call to `getnode` in `display_all_data` and see where it gets you.

Comment: Thanks for comments I had to complete another homework which has to be finished by 10:30 today, I will check when I get the pc after 8 hours class today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking and checking the provided source code, there are multiple problems due to a misunderstanding of the `malloc()`/`free()` of a node in a linked-list.

1. To add a node into a linked-list, it shall be allocated and initialize before,
2. When using a pointer to an allocated node, neither allocate or free that pointer,
3. A node added to a linked-list could be freed only after remove it or when the linked-list is delete.

Following those rules, here are the detected errors:

**Error 1** : In the `enter_new_data()`, an unexpected `freenode(p);`.

> The node `p` has been linked... Don't freed it.

```
// if there is no any node yet, add node p as first node
if(students == NULL) {
    students = p;
}
else {
    conductor = students; // assign linked-list to the conductor to traverse
    // reach the last node
    while (conductor->next != NULL)
    {
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    conductor->next = p; // append the node p to the linked list
}
// NO !!!!
freenode(p); // set free node p
```

**Error 2** : In the `display_all_data()`, unexpected free/malloc of `conductor`.

> The variable `conductor` is only a temporary pointer used to explored
>   the linked-list (Not allocated).

```
// NO !!!!
freenode(conductor);
// NO !!!!
conductor = getnode();

conductor = students; // assign linked-list to the conductor to traverse

if (conductor != NULL ) { /* Makes sure there is a place to start */
```

**Error 3** : minor error in `display_all_data()`, to explore all items the linked-list use node pointer instead of next pointer.

> Test by `( conductor != NULL)` to explore also the last item.

```
    while ( conductor != NULL) //->next != 0)
    {
        printf("\n%s%7d%18d%15s",conductor->name,conductor->age,
            conductor->student_no,conductor->nationality); // record
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I had to complete another homework which has to be finished by 10:30 today, I will check when I get the pc after 8 hours class today. But I got that why I mustn't use free node and other points, I will feedback when I tried.

Comment: Hello again, tank you so much @J. Piquard for the perfect answer, I was thinking in wrong way with new node altough I know pointers. Anyway, it's working properly, thanks to you.

Comment: @AydınBulut, one function is missing in your source code `if(opt == 2){ // removing record`. Removing node is a very good practice with structure pointer and Linked-List.

Comment: yes, I am coding it write now. And I assigned code a library program most probably whish will contain linked-list and so many but I just allowed to use stdio.h :S. I hope will handle it.

Comment: I just completed and shared above in the question the final program.